# Is it possible to control citr citation to follow APA style? (remove parentheses)

Tags: r-markdown

I'm using citr and zotero in R markdown to insert citation in a paper. It works well but when I need to cite  something (let's say another paper) inside parentheses, the year of that paper is still inside parentheses. How can I get rid of that?

Example:

`(e.g. @bartovRewardsMeetingBeating2002, @brownEffectEarningsSurprises2009)`

gives me  (e.g. Bartov, Givoly, and Hayn (2002), Brown, Hillegeist, and Lo (2009)). What I want to do is to get rid of the parentheses around year 2002 and 2009.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: by using [ ] instead of ( ), I got rid of the parentheses, but it seems the second citation does not work (it shows @brownEffectEarningsSurprises2009 instead of Brown, Hillegeist, and Lo 2009)